# is it possiable Swift file with Alamofire Used in objective-c Project or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, alamofire

I have so many files in Swift and for WebService calling I have used Alamofire framework with pod file and now all file I want change in Objective-C project, then XCode give me error like **Alamofire not found**,

is possible or not ? if YES then how ?

[image]

Comment: First un comment `use_frameworks!`  and update your pod with  `update pod` command and clean ypur project and check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try these Steps:

- Try Project>Clean>Build
- Try clearing derived Data.Re-Launch Xcode.
- Make sure you are not Opening xcodeproj instead of xcworkspace.
- Check  build settings > Framework Search Paths folder is the one
  where your frameworks are, for **both your Target and Project**.If the
  frameworks are placed in your project directory, set the framework
  search path to $(SRCROOT).

Hope something works

Comment: cross check you build settings > Framework Search Paths for both Project as well as Targets

Comment: only one target in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try below-

1. delete Alamofire from pod file
2. execute 'pod update' command
3. Add Alamofire in pod file again
4. execute 'pod install' command

Don't forget to use 'use_frameworks!' in pod file

Hopefully it will work!